# Calcular la diferencia entre horas en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo obtengo diferencia entre dos horas?

Por ejemplo, entre `07:30` y `09:00`, para que me diga la diferencia en minutos, segundos y horas.

Comment: Indica por favor que motor de base de datos, las soluciones, para oracle, sqlserver, mysql, etc son distintas.

Comment: Utilizo Wamp Server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con la función **TIMEDIFF**

`SELECT TIMEDIFF("07:30:00", "09:00:00");`

Aquí tienes el [manual de referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).